# Search in almost sorted array

Tags: java, algorithm, search

Given an array of nonnegative integers such as:

1. All elements are sorted except that array can be filled with zeroes
2. There are at most k sequential zeroes
3. If we take all zeroes out we get sorted array of positive integers

Example 3 0 0 4 7 9 0 0 0 0 11 15 0 19 20 0 0 31 40 0

For k=4

We need function kAlmostSearch(int[] a, int num) if k is constant but unknown for us.

I am trying to modify Binary Search but not sure how exactly I can do it.

Task only constraint is that k is not given, we only know it's constant and less than array size. And k is considered when time complexity is calculated.

It cannot be done better if it is 0 almost sorted than O(log n), so I am trying as I said to modify binary search that should possibly give a O(k* log n) because each time array size decreases we calculate closest nonzero element from both side finite number of times.

```
public static int closestLeft(int a[], int index){
    

    int current=index;

    while(current>=0 && a[current]==0){
        current--;
    }

    if(current<0){
        return -1;
     }

    return current;
}


public static int closestRight(int a[], int index){

    int current=index;

    while(current<=a.length-1 && a[current]==0){
        current++;
    }

    if(current>a.length-1){
        return -1;
    }

    return current;
}


public static int kAlmostSearch(int a[], int num){

    int lo=0, hi=a.length-1, mid, closestLeft, closestRight;

    while(lo<=hi){
    
        mid=(lo+hi)/2;
     
        if(a[mid]==0){

            if(closestLeft(a,mid)==-1){

                mid=closestRight(a,mid);

            }esle if(closestRight(a,mid)==-1){
              
                mid=closestLeft(a,mid);
            }else{
            /*how am I supposed to move here*/
            }
         }
    
        if(a[mid]==num){
            return mid;
        }
        if(a[mid]<num){
            lo=mid+1;
        }else{
            hi=mid-1;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252864/discussion-on-question-by-astropower-search-in-almost-sorted-array); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

To establish an efficient algorithm, having a O(log) time complexity, we could follow these guidelines:

- In one iteration of the binary-search loop no more than *k* zero values should be visited;
- The same (zero) value should not be visited more than once

An idea would be to look "around" the `mid` index that the binary search algorithm would determine, looking for a non-zero value. So we would first look at `a[mid]`, then `a[mid-1]` `a[mid+1]` `a[mid-2]`, ...etc. If this search gets out of the `low..high` range, then this means there is no non-zero value in that range and the search should return -1 (failure)

When the `low..high` range is narrowed down, then this should exclude the zeroes that were already checked.

Here is an implementation:

```java
    public static int kAlmostSearch(int[] a, int num) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = a.length;
        
        while (low < high) {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            // Look around for non zero value:
            int m = mid, add = -1;
            while (a[m] == 0) {
                m += add;
                // If there is no non-zero value in the range [low, high): not found
                if (m < low || m >= high) return -1;
                add = -add + (add > 0 ? -1 : 1);
            }
            if (a[m] == num) return mid;
            // When narrowing the window, make sure to exclude the zeroes we already saw
            if (num < a[m]) {
                high = Math.min(m, mid);
            } else {
                low = Math.max(m, mid) + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

NB: In this code, `high` is such that `a[high]` is not part of the current range.

Comment: Any feedback to this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reply directly to @trincot as I haven't gained enough reputation yet, but I think there's a minor bug in his solution. Running the following code will result in a false answer:

```
int[] a = new int[] {0, 1, 0, 3, 0};
System.out.println(kAlmostSearch(a, 3));
/// output: 4
```

This is due to this line:

```
if (a[m] == num) return mid;
```